# import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

Tags: reactjs, icons, react-native, vector-icons

Can I import react-native-vector-icons/font-awesome and react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons on same screen?
Basically I want to use both font-awesome and Ionicons icons on same screen for different icons?

```
Example-
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/font-awesome';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Comment: Did you try to use 'import as' ?
import {Icon as Icon1} from 'react-native-vector-icons/font-awesome';
import {Icon as Icon2} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Because FontAwesome and Ionicons are exported as defaults, you can import them with any name, like so

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import IonIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

and in your `render()` method use like

```
<FontAwesomeIcon name="github" size={16} color="red">
<IonIcon name="github" size={16} color="blue">
```